# Interfacing Parallel Port in Python

Tags: python

I need a tutorial or perhaps more on using Python to print data from a PARALLEL port. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The first hit on Google revealed http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyparallel.html ; you could either use the library directly, or if the license is incompatible, you can still learn from their code. Alternatively you can use ctypes perhaps to load a native library.

Comment: @ninjagecko: It seems the actual code is missing - there's pyserial, but there's no `parallel` module within, even though it's mentioned in the "documentation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned PyParallel package is now available on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparallel

I tested it successfully with GNU/Linux (Xubuntu 15.10) and Python 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at pyserial. http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/ and examples: http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html

I have some more examples, just need to find them.

Edit: Sorry, I meant pyParallel http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyparallel.html

Some examples:

http://orionrobots.co.uk/PyParallel
http://pyserial.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pyserial/trunk/pyparallel/examples/lcd.py?revision=398&view=markup